# how to use reflection properly (special case) JAVA

Tags: java, android, reflection

I hava a POJO class which has a lot of getters. Now I’m using the class `Method` from the java.lang.reflect package to get all the get methods from that class. I want to invoke those getters but I don’t have idea how. `arraylistFilter` is an `Arraylist<pojo>` that contains the result from my request. `Option` is an Object Field data type which is the one that actually has like 100 getters. How can I get each of them without needed to call 1 by 1. what goes in my .??? there is where I want to be able to invoke my getters.

```
try {
    Class<? extends Options> testObject = new Options().getClass();
    Method[] methods = testObject.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        String name = method.getName();
        if (method.getName().startsWith("get") &&
            method.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListFilter.size(); i++) {
                arrayListFilter.get(i).getOptions().???;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something with the exceptions
}
```

Comment: `method.invoke(name.substring(3))` does't look right. `method.invoke(...)` expects instance of a class on which you would normally call your method. For instance in case when you are trying to simulate `yourInstance.method()`  you need to call `method.invoke(yourInstance)`.

Comment: BTW if your POJO follows JavaBean convention you can use classes from `java.bean` package like `Introspector` to get information of bean like its properties.

Comment: One of advantages of Introspector is that it also handles cases where properties are of `boolean` type since in JavaBeans accessors of such properties start with `isPropertyName()` not `getPropertyName()` like `isMarried()`.

Comment: ok I made a mistake leaving that line of code where I try to invoke my method that I got from doing reflection that part is working right , what Im asking is how can invoke my method where my .??? is in the code is where I suppose to invoke my getters, what’s next??

Comment: yes, ..... so the piece of code I pasted here is doing reflection and obtaining all methods with the word "get". I don’t know how can invoke them. in this special case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
try {
    Method[] methods = Options.class.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        String name = method.getName();
        if (method.getName().startsWith("get") &&
            method.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListFilter.size(); i++) {
                Object value = method.invoke(arrayListFilter.get(i).getOptions());
                // The actual type of 'value' will depend on the getter's
                // formal return type AND the actual type it returns.
                // When the return type is a primitive, it is mapped to
                // the corresponding wrapper.  
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something with the exceptions
}
```

We have simplified / fixed the code that gets the `Method` objects, and have changed `getGenericParameterTypes()` to `getParameterTypes()`.  Generic type parameters are not relevant here, but you *do* need to filter out getters that require arguments, because there is no way to supply sensible argument values.